# Как избавиться от мерцания при выводе в консоль?

Tags: c++, c, консоль

Необходимо реализовать в консоли мини-игру типа арканоида, змейки.
Я решил обновлять картинку в консоли следующим образом:

1. `system("cls");`
2. выводим в консоль новую картинку.

Проблема такая — при обновлении картинки происходит мелькание заново отрисовываемых символов.

Какими путями можно избавиться от  такого, чтобы в консоли картинка обновлялась наименее заметно для человеческого глаза?

Comment: В буквальном смысле никак

Comment: Не делать каждый раз cls, а просто перерисовывать изменившиеся части картинки.

Comment: Используйте WinAPI и пишите прямо в консольный буфер. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно делать буферизованный вывод на экран, примерно так

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>

void move(int & dir, ::std::size_t & pos, ::std::size_t max)
{
    switch (rand() % 20)
    {
        case 0: dir = 0; return;
        case 5: dir = -1; break;
        case 10: dir = 1; break;
        case 15: dir *= -1; break;
    }
    if (0 < dir)
    {
        if ((max - 1) == pos)
        {
            pos = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            pos += 1;
        }
    }
    else if (dir < 0)
    {
        if (0 == pos)
        {
            pos = max - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            pos -= 1;
        }
    }
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    constexpr ::std::size_t const width{80};
    constexpr ::std::size_t const height{30};
    ::std::array<wchar_t, width * height> buf{};
    for (::std::size_t char_index{}; buf.size() != char_index; ++char_index)
    {
        buf[char_index] = (0 != ((char_index + 1) % width)) ? L' ' : L'\n';
    }
    ::std::size_t col_pos{};
    ::std::size_t row_pos{};
    int x_dir{};
    int y_dir{};
    ::std::array<::std::size_t, 42> tail{};
    ::std::size_t cur_tail_end_index{};
    ::HANDLE const output{::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)};
    ::CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursor_info{sizeof(cursor_info), FALSE}; // hide cursor
    ::SetConsoleCursorInfo(output, ::std::addressof(cursor_info));
    for (;;)
    {
        buf[tail[cur_tail_end_index]] = L'·';
        ++cur_tail_end_index;
        cur_tail_end_index %= tail.size();
        buf[tail[cur_tail_end_index]] = L' ';
        ::move(x_dir, col_pos, width - 1);
        ::move(y_dir, row_pos, height);
        tail[cur_tail_end_index] = width * row_pos + col_pos;
        buf[tail[cur_tail_end_index]] = L'O';
        ::SetConsoleCursorPosition(output, {});
        ::WriteConsoleW(output, buf.data(), buf.size() - 1, {}, {});
        ::Sleep(1000 / 60);
    }
}
```

Примерный вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: написать много точек, чтоб выводить много точек?...

Answer (score 1):

pdcurses - это порт ncurses на windows

работает так:

https://youtu.be/Kcv84FVszkc

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать заменить

```
while (true){
    // здесь основной цикл просчётов
    system(cls);
    draw();
}
```

на

```
while (true){
    // здесь основной цикл просчётов
    system(cls);
    draw();
    sleep(150);  // спим 150 миллисекунд
}
```

Иногда игра очень простая и просчёты очень быстрые, а как следствие рисовать дольше чем просчитывать. В общем попробуйте просто добавить слип. Может помочь!

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE hCon;
    COORD cPos;
    hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    cPos.X = 0 ;
    cPos.Y =0;
    Setub();
    while (gameover != true)
    {
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hCon, cPos);
        Draw();
        Input();
        Logic();
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```