# есть ли команда для заморозки

Tags: c++

Написал код. Код выводит оцифрованную сетку. Но при добавлении чего-либо, сетка
смещается. Есть ли команда или строчка, которая замораживает сетку(из символов) и не дает ей сместиться.(visual studio 17)
(я знаю, что умные люди создают формочки, но я не умею и компьютер не позволяет)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <stack>
#include <conio.h>
#include <numeric>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    Person(string name, double score, int age)
    {
        this->Name = name;
        this->Score = score;
        this->Age = age;
    }

    string Name;
    double Score;
    int Age;
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int a = 0, b = 0,w;
    int x = 5;
    int y = 10;
    string s = " ";
    vector <Person> people
    {
        Person(s,a,b),
        Person(s,a,b),
        Person(s,a,b),
        Person(s,a,b),
        Person(s,a,b),
        Person(s,a,b),
    };

    cout << "1) Просмотр" << endl
        << "2) Изменения" << endl;
    cin >> w;
    system("cls");
    switch (w)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
            cout << "\t";
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                cout << "__";
            }
            cout << "\n";
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                cout << "\t";
                cout << "| ";
                cout << "           ";
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                cout << "  ";
                cout << "| ";
                cout << "        ";
            }

            cout << endl;

        }
        break;

    case 2:

        break;

    default: cout << "такого пункта нет" << endl;
    }


    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ага. Как в фотошопе - кнопка "сделать красиво" =) А серьёзно - я ничего не понял, код показать можете ?

Comment: все? вроде все нормально

Comment: Наверное вам надо попробовать выводить буферризованный текст. см [](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811009/c-vs-Мини-игра-в-консоли/811056#811056) То бишь рисуете сетку в буфере а потом заполняете пробелы ничего никуда не сдвигая.