# Как ускорить вывод в консоль с FillConsoleOutputCharacter()

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте пытаюсь сделать видео BadApple в консоли, но мне не хватает скорости вывода символов даже с функцией FillConsoleOutputCharacter().   Вот мой код:

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    
    PlaySoundW(TEXT("BadAppleMusic.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME && SND_ASYNC);
    int frame = 43;

    while (frame <= 6571) 
    {
        showImage(frame, hOut);
        frame++;
    }
}

void showImage(int index, HANDLE hOut)
{
    DWORD written;
    string name = "BadApple" + to_string(index) + ".png";
    Mat notsizedimage = imread("D:/BadApple/BadApple C++/Frames/" + name);
    Size size(100, 50);
    Mat image;
    resize(notsizedimage, image, size, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
    COORD point = { 0,0 };
    

    for (int x = 0; x < image.rows; x++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.cols; y++)
        {
            Vec3b vec = image.at<Vec3b>(x, y);
            point = { short(y), short(x) };
            if (vec.val[0] < 127 && vec.val[1] < 127 && vec.val[2] < 127)
            {   
                FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hOut, '#', 1, point, &written);

            }
            else 
            {                               
                FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hOut, ' ', 1, point, &written);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Извините за кривой код.

Comment: 1 - Заранее загрузите все картинки в память и преобразуйте в строки. 2 - выводите строки целиком, а не по одному символу - так будет намного быстрее.

Comment: Куда мне 6к изображений загрузить ? ) В массив что-ли?

Comment: ну так одна картинка в тексте это 80*25 около 2 кб. 6к картинок - это 12 мб. Если это не 8086 или микроардуинка, то вполне реально.

Comment: Я пытаюсь загружать именно изображение потому-что в txt файл как то криво загружается текст.

Comment: Выводить надо не по одному символу, а сразу весь видимый буфер обновлять. см [C++ (VS). Мини-игра в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811009/c-vs-%d0%9c%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8/811056#811056) Этот вопрос по сути дубликат.

Comment: Извините, но там ничего не понятно. Я решил сделать всё простым выводом строки через WriteConsoleCharacter.

Comment: А чем вам WriteConsoleOutput(), собственно, не угодил? Загружаете вашу "картинку" в массив структур CHAR_INFO, затем выводите его на экран целиком. Функция работает очень быстро, - на моём ПК в разрешении 147x40 символов спокойно выдаёт около 400 FPS - быстрее и придумать нельзя, как для консоли!..

Comment: Уже сделал всё  через WriteConsoleCharacter() всё прекрасно работает. Спасибо за помощь всем.