# Вывод строки в разном цвете

Tags: c++

Делаю ascii анимацию. Нужно задать цвет каждому отдельному символу, но перебор символов каждой строки и ее вывод занимает гораздо больше времени чем вывод полной строки. Можно ли как-то заранее задать цвет каждому символу и выводить строку полностью. Для задания цвета пользовался SetConsoleTextAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Следует [наполнять сразу весь экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811009/c-vs-%d0%9c%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8/811056#811056) и сразу же задавать атрибуты для всего экрана используя [FillConsoleOutputAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/fillconsoleoutputattribute).