# Обновление кадра на консоли

Tags: c++, консоль

https://pastebin.com/mG5af2HL - тут весь код

Пытаюсь реализовать двойную буферизацию при обновлении кадра на консоли. В файлах находятся отдельные кадры анимации.

Содержимое всех файлов храню в векторе data. Когда итерируюсь по очередному кадру анимации, вывожу только те символы, на месте которых в прошлом кадре стояли другие символы:

```
            if(data[i][j][k] != v[j][k]){ // вектор v хранит прошлый кадр

                setCursorPosition(j, k);
                wcout << data[i][j][k];
                Sleep(100);

            }
```

Но все выводится криво. Где я ошибся?

И ещё, когда кадры храню не в файлах, а непосредственно в векторе, то все выводится нормально:
https://pastebin.com/K63fYPnN

https://dropmefiles.com/wXfqC - сами файлы

Comment: А как это может помочь? Ведь я же вывожу символ в определенной позиции консоли

Comment: Не помогло(((((

Comment: Может с кодировками проблема? Сложно сказать, не имея визуальную картинку.

Comment: сами файлы в utf-8.

Comment: *"вывожу только те символы, на месте которых в прошлом кадре стояли другие символы"* - это как раз отказ от двойной буферизации в пользу кучи мелких обновлений. пример буферизованного вывода https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811009/c-vs-%d0%9c%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8/811056#811056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема возникает в процессе чтения из файла, а именно в настройке локали для потоковых операций.

Добавьте в начало:

```
#include <codecvt>
```

После объявления потока настроим локаль:

```
wifstream input;
input.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
```

Возможно вызовы `_setmode` потребуется вернуть на место.
Должно заработать.

P.S. Пользуйтесь отладчиком, помогает.