# "Мигает" вывод в консоль

Tags: c++, буферизация, fps

При выводе в консоль происходят "мерцания", так как отсутствует двойная буферизация. Задача - избавиться от мерцания, ЛЮБЫМ способом. Можно и при помощи двойной буферизации. Любому решению буду благодарен.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void drow(char x);

int main() {
    char one = '0';
    char two = '#';
    int i = 1;
    while (i) {
        drow(one); // 0.1 sec отрисовка
        system("cls"); // 0.1 sec стереть
        drow(two); // 0.1 sec отрисовка
        system("cls"); // 0.1 sec стереть
    }
    return 0;
}

void drow(char x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("%c", x);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Сократите вызов системной функции. Т.е. замените ваш цикл на заготовленные массивы строк которые будут перезаполняться по мере необходимости, и выводите строки разом, это первая оптимизация на пути к отсутствию мерцания(функцию printf вызывать сразу для строки а не для еденичного символа, а лучше сразу с переносами строк).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811009/c-vs-%d0%9c%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8/811056#811056

Comment: вторая оптимизация на пути к отсутствию мерцания - отказ от cls в пользу управления кареткой, т.е. точечное затирание ваших же символов пробелами(например).

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Спасибо, интересный способ. Отдельное спасибо за ссылку с буферизацией.

Comment: Это именно тот способ который описан по ссылке из второго комментария, просто там еще несколько оптимизаций до которых вы и сами дойдете пока реализуете управление кареткой и видеобуфер ;)