# вывод в консоль си

Tags: c

Я хочу работать с консолью в качестве двумерного массива, то есть иметь возможность выводить в определенную ячейку. Можно ли так сделать? Я пытался через fsetpos но для этого надо иметь размер консоли. Можно ли обойтись без этого, или какую-то идею

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Как минимум, это зависит от операционной системы.

Comment: пример для winapi https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811009/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%86%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c/811056#811056

Comment: Посмотрите на [curses](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses) или на [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)